# .htaccess; Rewrite folder name in URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've many links like this:

```
www.example.com/my_folder/something/33
www.example.com/my_folder/anything/81
```

How can I rewrite `my_folder` to `folder123`.

Means: If I type `www.example.com/folder123/something/33` I'm getting the content of `www.example.com/my_folder/something/33` but the URL remains `www.example.com/folder123/something/33`.

How can I do that with `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple rewrite rule as this:

```
RewriteEngine On   

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+my_folder(/\S*)?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /folder123%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^folder123(/.*)?$ my_folder$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, that works. But how can I redirect make a 301 redirect from `my_folder` to `folder123`? If I type `www.example.com/my_folder/something/33` it should 301 redirect to `www.example.com/folder123/something/33`.